# Android application crashing in AsyncThread

Tags: android, android-asynctask

So my application starts up and works for the first fragment of the viewpager but then crashes when loading the second fragment of the viewpager. Any help would be much appreciated.
Here is the source code:

```
public class PreviousWord extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saveInstanceState) {
    View v = (inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_previous_word, container, false)); 
    new GetWord().execute();
    return v;
}

private class GetWord extends AsyncTask<Void,Void, Void>{
       private Element data=null;
       private Element data2=null;
       private Element date=null;
       private String wordName;
       private String dates;
       private TextView date1;
       private TextView date2;
       private TextView date3;
       private TextView date4;
       private TextView date5;
       private TextView date6;
       private ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
       private ArrayList<String> dateList = new ArrayList<String>();


       @Override
       protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) { 
            Document doc = null;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.urbandictionary.com/").get();
                for(int i = 1; i<7; i=i+1){

                    data = doc.getElementsByClass("word").get(i);
                    data2 = data.select("a[href]").first();
                    wordName = data2.text();
                    wordList.add(wordName);

                    date = doc.getElementsByClass("smallcaps").get(i);
                    dates = date.text();
                    dateList.add(dates);

                    date1 = (TextView) DailyWord.v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
                    date2 = (TextView) DailyWord.v.findViewById(R.id.text3);
                    date3 = (TextView) DailyWord.v.findViewById(R.id.text5);
                    date4 = (TextView) DailyWord.v.findViewById(R.id.text7);
                    date5 = (TextView) DailyWord.v.findViewById(R.id.text9);
                    date6 = (TextView) DailyWord.v.findViewById(R.id.text11);

                }

            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            date1.setText(dateList.get(0));
            date2.setText(dateList.get(1));
            date3.setText(dateList.get(2));
            date4.setText(dateList.get(3));
            date5.setText(dateList.get(4));
            date6.setText(dateList.get(5));
         }

    }

}
```

Here is my LogCat:

```
12-10 22:25:50.055: W/dalvikvm(19935): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40fbb2a0)
12-10 22:25:50.065: E/AndroidRuntime(19935): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-10 22:25:50.065: E/AndroidRuntime(19935): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-10 22:25:50.065: E/AndroidRuntime(19935):    at com.dictionary.urbanword.PreviousWord$GetWord.onPostExecute(PreviousWord.java:75)
12-10 22:25:50.065: E/AndroidRuntime(19935):    at com.dictionary.urbanword.PreviousWord$GetWord.onPostExecute(PreviousWord.java:1)
12-10 22:25:50.065: E/AndroidRuntime(19935):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
12-10 22:25:50.065: E/AndroidRuntime(19935):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
12-10 22:25:50.065: E/AndroidRuntime(19935):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
12-10 22:25:50.065: E/AndroidRuntime(19935):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-10 22:25:50.065: E/AndroidRuntime(19935):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-10 22:25:50.065: E/AndroidRuntime(19935):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
12-10 22:25:50.065: E/AndroidRuntime(19935):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-10 22:25:50.065: E/AndroidRuntime(19935):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-10 22:25:50.065: E/AndroidRuntime(19935):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
12-10 22:25:50.065: E/AndroidRuntime(19935):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
12-10 22:25:50.065: E/AndroidRuntime(19935):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Hi line 75 is:
    date1.setText(dateList.get(0));

Comment: So either your TextView is null, or dateList is null. Check if dateList has anything in it, i.e. `Log.i(something, dateList);`

Comment: Also, please move the creation of date1...date6 to the constructor of GetWord. You even set them 6 times in the loop right now.

Comment: Yeah I just realised that, was a typo with the end bracket of the for loop I've changed that now.

Comment: It appears that it is the TextView that is null, any ideas on how I could possibly fix this?

Comment: @user1825241 you need to use the inflated view object to  initialize views. what you are doing is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `activity_previous_word.xml` has all the textviews in it change your code to

```
 public class PreviousWord extends Fragment {
     private Element data=null;
       private Element data2=null;
       private Element date=null;
       private String wordName,dates;
       private TextView date1,date2,date3,date4,date5,date6;
       private ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
       private ArrayList<String> dateList = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saveInstanceState) {
    View v = (inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_previous_word, container, false)); 

                    date1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
                    date2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text3);
                    date3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text5);
                    date4 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text7);
                    date5 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text9);
                    date6 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text11);  
    new GetWord().execute();
    return v;
}

private class GetWord extends AsyncTask<Void,Void, Void>{



       @Override
       protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) { 
            Document doc = null;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.urbandictionary.com/").get();
                for(int i = 1; i<7; i=i+1){

                    data = doc.getElementsByClass("word").get(i);
                    data2 = data.select("a[href]").first();
                    wordName = data2.text();
                    wordList.add(wordName);

                    date = doc.getElementsByClass("smallcaps").get(i);
                    dates = date.text();
                    dateList.add(dates);

                }

            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            date1.setText(dateList.get(0));
            date2.setText(dateList.get(1));
            date3.setText(dateList.get(2));
            date4.setText(dateList.get(3));
            date5.setText(dateList.get(4));
            date6.setText(dateList.get(5));
         }

    }

}
```

`findViewById` looks for a view with the id mentioned in the current inflated layout. So you need to use the inflated view object to initialize your views.